# Discord.js Display Server User Count separately from Server Bot Member Count

Tags: filter, discord.js

I am trying to create a serverinfo command for my Discord.js Bot. I am trying to get the Discord Server User Count separate from the Server's Bot Count. I have been told to use the `.filter` but I don't understand how to filter the bot count from the user count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well from `guild.members.cache` you'll get a Collection with all the members (users and bots). With `.filter` you can "exclude" items of a collection if they don't match something. For example:

```
guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
```

Should return the number of members that aren't bots on `guild`.

Answer (score 1):

User filter:

```js
client.guilds.get('Your guild id').members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
```