# How can i get discord get membercount with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

i need a nodejs suggestion. I want to set activity for my bot like this: Right now 15.954 user is registered.

```
bot.on("ready", () => {
    bot.user.setActivity("Right Now .... user is registered.");
})
```

How can i do that? im looking docs but i cant use memberCount action.

My language: Node.js
Platform: Discord

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.js Display Server User Count separately from Server Bot Member Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835018/discord-js-display-server-user-count-separately-from-server-bot-member-count)

Comment: Am already read this solution but doesnt work man. This is not duplicate.

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: @JBis its looking like that: http://prntscr.com/pyovq4

Comment: Edit your question to include what you have tried and what the result was. (Actual result bs expected result)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `client.guilds.size`.

Example:

````js
bot.on("ready", () => {
    bot.user.setActivity(`Right Now ${bot.guilds.size} users are registered.`);
})```
````